# In singular value decomposition why is $V$ orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have studied SVD from multiple resources and what I have understood is that in ($AV = \Sigma U$), A is a transformation matrix, $V$ is the matrix on which transformation is applied. $\Sigma$ is scaling matrix and $U$ is rotation matrix.
What I don't understand is how $V$ can be an orthogonal matrix. It could be any matrix, why are we assuming that it's an orthogonal matrix ?

Comment: I like to think of SVD as a computational method that takes in a matrix and spits out three. The matrix it takes in is $A$ (any matrix), and it spits out $U,V,\Sigma$. Essentially what SVD tells you is that $A$ can be written as a composition of three linear operations: orthogonal (rotation), scaling, then another orthogonal, i.e., $A=U\Sigma V^\top$. To answer your question, you're not "assuming" $V$ is orthogonal. The orthogonality of $V$ (and $U$) is simply a property of the particular decomposition of $A$ that is performed by SVD.

Answer (score 0):

In the SVD of a real matrix $A$ of order $m\times n$, the eigenvectors of $A^TA$ make up the columns of $V$, while the eigenvectors of $AA^T$  make up the columns of $U$. Now, as $A^TA$ is a symmetric matrix, i.e., $(A^TA)^T = A^TA$, and every symmetric real matrix of order $n$, has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. By normalizing them you can construct the orthogonal matrix $V$ such that $V^TV = I$. In other words, the orghotonoality of $V$ and $U$ stems from the very construction of the SVD, and it is not assumed apriori.